# Read File (Column and looping) and ssh

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, solaris, hp-ux

I have 1 input file contains  username and hostname  example:

```
ID1  host1
ID2  host2
ID3  host3
ID4  host1
```

Totally no script created yet.

My Question
How I  can make the script read username and do ssh based on host to do ssh.

```
ssh -q $host 'grep $user /etc/passwd'
```

and it looping until finish.

Thank you in advanced 
very Appreciate

script read the input file and read column 1 and column 2 as a input and then loop until the all line in the input are read.

do have

output , will show the result based on the input ID and do ssh to get the output.

Answer (score 0):

```
while read -r user host;
do
  echo "${user}" # The ID?
  `your code`
done < inputfile
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need an entire script for this, simply try this:

```
$ cat filename.txt  | awk '{system("ssh "$2" grep "$1" /etc/passwd;")}'
```

or

```
$ cat filename.txt | awk '{system("ssh "$2" getent passwd "$1";")}'
```

Comment: itChi & Guiseppe Kalzone TQ for the update .. let me try  , actually after grep  I need to delete  the account from /etc/passwd. let me try on both code.  again many thanks

Comment: not work for me - empty output. if remoce xargs it show the syntax but it not run.

Comment: Damn, sorry didn't check the command, let's remove the xargs part and run it with awk. I'll update the command